# Почему получаю ошибку в этом сценарии?

Tags: php

```
<?php

class A
{
    public function a($at)
    {
        echo $at;
    }

    public function b()
    {
        echo 'Test';
    }
}

$ac = new A();
$ac->b();
```

Получаю ошибку: `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function A::a(), 0 passed`

Я же не вызываю этот метод...

Comment: А на какой версии Вы выполняете данный скрипт? Если что, у меня на PHP 8.1.6 никаких ошибок не видно

Comment: @4500zenja `PHP 7.4.28 (cli) (built: Feb 17 2022 16:17:19) ( NTS )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если смотреть на версию `PHP 7.4.x` и старше, то, помимо данной ошибки, будет выводиться и следующее:

```
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors
in a future version of PHP; A has a deprecated constructor in 
/home/user/scripts/code.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function A::a(),
0 passed in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 16 and exactly 1 expected in 
/home/user/scripts/code.php:5 
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/scripts/code.php(16): A->a()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 5
```

Это означает, что данная версия будет считать метод `a()` как конструктор класса `A` — да, регистр здесь неважен. Ранее, с [`PHP 5.3.3`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), при попытке выводе данного метода выводилось предупреждение о скором снятии данной фичи, что и было сделано в `PHP 8.x`.

Я предлагаю два варианта:

1. Перейти на `PHP 8.x`;
2. Заменить имя метода на какое-нибудь другое, не равное 'a' или 'A'

Answer (score 1):

Тут проблема отчасти php.

Видимо при разборе парсер приводит имя класса к нижнему регистру и в итоге получается, что вызывается конструктор.  В ранних версиях *PHP* конструктор объявлялся с таким же именем, как сам класс. Потом это устарело и рекомендовано было использовать `__construct`.

Как итог, сейчас в текущем коде метод `a` понимается как конструктор. Отсюда и ошибка. Если назовёте его по-другому - ошибка исчезнет.

С версии 8.0 это тоже починили